# Angular2 @ContentChildren not populated inside parent <ng-content>

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components, angular2-ngcontent

**ISSUE:**

@ContentChildren does not seem to work on Parent `<ng-content>` containers.
Even if the content is a child of the component.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/J5itJmDfwKwtBsG6IveP?p=preview

**NOTE**: I Am using `{descendants: true}`

**Example Code:**

Main HTML:

```
<div>
  <child>
    <test></test>
    <test></test>
    <test></test>
  </child>
  <br><br>
  <parent>
    <test></test>
    <test></test>
    <test></test>
  </parent>
</div>
```

Child Component:

```
<h2>Child</h2>
<parent>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</parent>
```

Parent Component:

```
<h3>Parent</h3>
<ng-content></ng-content>
<div class='length'>Line count : {{length}}</div>
```

**Problem**
The length of the `test` component is 0 for the child component, but 3 for the parent component.

---

Detailed Code:

```
import {
  Component, ContentChildren, Directive
} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({selector: 'test'})
export class Test {}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <h3>Parent</h3>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div class='length'>Line count : {{length}}</div>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent  {

  @ContentChildren(Test, {descendants: true}) private tests : QueryList<Test>;

  constructor() { }

  get length () {
    return this.tests.length;
  }
}
```

---

```
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
  <h2>Child</h2>
  <parent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </parent>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent  {

  constructor() { }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you reverse parent child? Child should be inside parent and not vice versa. Anyway this is exact problem I am came into. And documentation does not say anything that it should not be working. https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContentChildren` will count only directives assigned to the `current Component`. For your situation, while assigning `test` directive to `ChildComponent`, you should count directives at `ChildComponent` itself.

refer this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/H8pkclndwSOciKhcKDBT?p=preview) I forked from you.

Comment: This solution works nice. I feel like angular should be able to do the above functionality tho :(

Comment: @KevinUpton oh, I also feel like so before. But I still didn't find anything after some research.